# 301 redirects for /blog to blog subdomain not working

Tags: htaccess, redirects, wordpress, 301-redirect

I just created a new subdomain for my blog so `blog.example.com` - it used to be `www.example.com/blog` so I am now trying to write 301 redirects from all my old `/blog` posts to the new `blog.example.com` URLs. I have placed the following code in my `htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://blog.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

However, do I put it after the `# END Wordpress` in the `htaccess` or am I missing something? Where in the `htaccess` file do I put this code or is it even the correct code?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

OR Do I need to write out

```
Redirect 301 /blog/example-post http://blog.example.com/example-post
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is your domain already canonicalised? ie. Can it only be accessed by the `www` subdomain (and the `blog` subdomain)? Does your `blog` subdomain point to the same document root as your main domain? Have you already changed the URL structure in WordPress itself? Have you actually tried this and what was the result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ...do I put it after the `# END Wordpress` in the htaccess or am I missing something?

No. Any external redirect should come *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` code block. ie. Before WP internally rewrites the request.

If you placed it *after* the WP code block it will simply be ignored, since WP will have already routed the request.

Otherwise your mod_rewrite redirect looks OK, assuming your old `/blog/` URL always has a trailing slash (to the "blog root"), the `blog` subdomain points to the same place on the filesystem as your main domain and you have already canonicalised the domain (ie. it can only be accessed via the `www` subdomain).

> ```
>  Redirect 301 /blog ....
> ```

You should avoid mixing `RewriteRule` (ie. mod_rewrite) and `Redirect` (ie. mod_alias) directives. Since these two directives belong to different modules they execute at *different times* during the request and you can end up with confusing conflicts if you are not careful. So, since you are already using mod_rewrite (WordPress directives) then you should stick to using mod_rewrite for any redirects.

It wouldn't matter were you placed the `Redirect` in your config file - it would still execute *after* the mod_rewrite directives.

Answer (score 2):

You want something like this using a [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)

```
Redirect permanent /blog http://blog.example.com/
```

The keyword permanent causes Apache to send an HTTP status of 301 Moved Permanently instead of 302 Found.

To use your method you can try this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://blog.example.com/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^blog/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Other than making www. optional, I'm not seeing how your rewrite rule is different than the ones that are not working in the question.  I think the problem may be related to the placement position in .htaccess rather than due to the rule itself.

Comment: It appears that your logic is backwards from what the OP is looking for... /blog to blog.example.com. Sorry. Cheers!!

Answer (score -3):

I had same problem, site was very very slow.

Changed [L,R=301] to [R=301,L] and problem solved.

Comment: "same problem"? The question is not about site speed. `[L,R=301]` and `[R=301,L]` are indentical, so it wasn't that that solved your problem. (?)